# What is LiveMesh Object and its connection with Silverlight 3.0

Tags: .net, silverlight, synchronization, mesh

I would like to understand that what is Mesh Object and its conection with silverlight, i am bit aware that it has got some relation with Local storage and then sync with the server data.

But i would like to understand it fundamentally so if anyone can provide any link to the article for conceptual understanding or Step by step implementation of LiveMesh in Silverlight 3.0 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesh is a syncronisation platform which can be used to sync contacts and files (both objects) across machines and a centralised cloud based desktop. When you make changes to one of these objects the changes are replicated to the other devices. You can use Silverlight 3 to create web apps that utilise Mesh, but you can also create then using .NET and the Mesh SDK.

You can download the SDK and code [samples](http://dev.live.com/liveframework/sdk/) here.