# What's a good cloud based file storage platform to use with Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, storage, cloud

I'm working on a Silverlight app that would allow a user to upload a few gigs of files to a hypothetical cloud based file store, then allow the user to view some data about those files later (more functionality than a file store).  Ideally I'd like to use a free, per-user store such as SkyDrive but I can't seem to find an API for that service (and read elsewhere on stack overflow that programmatic access violates their TOS).  Do any services fit this bill?  I've heard of Amazon S3 but I understand that'll cost some money - is anything free?

EDIT: Could Mesh be an option?
[What is LiveMesh Object and its connection with Silverlight 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061926/what-is-livemesh-object-and-its-connection-with-silverlight-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at using Azure as it offers a blob and table storage cloud infrastrucutre and will happily run silverlight applications in an azure web role. Currently there is no cost but this will change once it RTW's.

More info at http://www.azure.com/

Comment: Thanks!  Azure has the best Silverlight integration so I'm going with that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, nothing in this world is free when you're dealing with gigabytes of storage, plus the bandwith to put them in the cloud.

Amazon S3 is quite reasonable on its pricing.